# How to set text a textview in drawer header from shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Sorry for my English, 
I already set a text in drawer header from shared preferences 
**MainActivity.Java :**

```
 View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    setNama((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerName));
    setEmail((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerEmail));
    setGambar((CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar));
    gambarProfil=(CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);

    getNama().setText(sp.getString("fullname", ""));
    getEmail().setText(sp.getString("username", ""));

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(base_url+"foto_user/"+sp.getString("username","")+".jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blank).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE,NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(gambarProfil);
```

Then i have activity to change my fullname, username and picture profile

**Change Profile.java :**

```
 private void saveProfilPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("fullname", fullname.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("no_hp",no_hp.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("foto",username.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    //nama.setText(fullname.getText().toString());
}
```

My shared preferences value is already changed, but my drawer header keep storing an old value of my shared preferences, i think its because i must refresh the drawer but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where did you put your `getString()`?

Comment: @PERSISTENCE my getString is in MainActivity.java and putString is in ChangeProfle.java

Comment: @PERSISTENCE my getString is in MainActivity.java and putString is in ChangeProfle.java

Comment: Update your UI on drawer open close

Answer (score 1):

Add `DrawerListener` to your `DrawerLayout` and update `NavigationView` header text from method `onDrawerOpened()`. This method will be called when its opened by clicking on drawer `toggle` icon or finger `swipe` from left to right.

**Update your code as below:**

```
// DrawerLayout
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

// ActionBarDrawerToggle
ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

// NavigationView
NavigationView mNavigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Views
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            // Update navigation header text
            updateNavigationViewHeader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }
    };

    // DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    .........
    ..................
}

public void updateNavigationViewHeader() {
    View header = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    setNama((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerName));
    setEmail((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerEmail));
    setGambar((CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar));
    gambarProfil=(CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);

    getNama().setText(sp.getString("fullname", ""));
    getEmail().setText(sp.getString("username", ""));
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(base_url+"foto_user/"+sp.getString("username","")+".jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blank).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE,NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(gambarProfil);

}
```

Comment: Though it's a bit old answer, but this solved my long-standing problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this code:

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    setNama((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerName));
    setEmail((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerEmail));
    setGambar((CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar));
    gambarProfil=(CircleImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);

    getNama().setText(sp.getString("fullname", ""));
    getEmail().setText(sp.getString("username", ""));

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(base_url+"foto_user/"+sp.getString("username","")+".jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.blank).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE,NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(gambarProfil);
```

after saving data in shared preferences

Comment: Thank u for answer, but those code are in different activity. How can i do that ? thank you

Comment: Thank u for answer, but those code are in different activity. How can i do that ? thank you

Comment: you may call recreate();' in this activity.